# Django import error: No module named models

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I keep receiving the error `Could not import movies.views. Error was: No module named models`

Here is my traceback:

```
    Environment:


    Request Method: GET
    Request URL: http://localhost:8000/movies/awesome-movie/

    Django Version: 1.3.1
    Python Version: 2.7.3
    Installed Applications:
    ['django.contrib.auth',
     'username_patch',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.sites',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.flatpages',
     'south',
     'tagging',
     'tagging_autocomplete',
     'accounts',
     'movies',
     'tracking',
     'djcelery',
     'pagination']
    Installed Middleware:
    ('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
     'pagination.middleware.PaginationMiddleware')


    Traceback:
    File "/Users/jeff/Code/filmlibrary/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
      101.                             request.path_info)
    File "/Users/jeff/Code/filmlibrary/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
      252.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
    File "/Users/jeff/Code/filmlibrary/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
      252.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
    File "/Users/jeff/Code/filmlibrary/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
      158.             return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name)
    File "/Users/jeff/Code/filmlibrary/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_callback
      167.             raise ViewDoesNotExist("Could not import %s. Error was: %s" % (mod_name, str(e)))

    Exception Type: ViewDoesNotExist at /movies/awesome-movie/
    Exception Value: Could not import movies.views. Error was: No module named models
```

I am not sure why I have this error. My code is as follows...

I have an django app called `tracking` and another called `movies`. I have a python file called `tracking.py` in the `tracking` app it consists of the following code:

**filmlibrary/tracking/tracking.py**

```
from movies.models import Movie
from tracking.models import MovieView

import os
import base64

def tracking_id(request):
    try:
        return request.session['tracking_id']
    except KeyError:
        request.session['tracking_id'] = base64.b64encode(os.urandom(36))
        return request.session['tracking_id']

def log_movie_view(request, movie):
    t_id = tracking_id(request)
    try:
        v = MovieView.objects.get(tracking_id=t_id, movie=movie)
        v.save()
    except MovieView.DoesNotExist:
        v = MovieView()
        v.movie = movie
        v.ip_address = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
        v.tracking_id = t_id
        v.user = None
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            v.user = request.user
        v.save()
```

The above is pretty basic stuff. My `views.py` in my `movies` app uses the tracking.py file here:

**filmlibrary/movies/views.py**

```
@login_required
def movie_details(request, slug, template_name="movies/movie_detail.html"):
    movie = get_object_or_404(Movie, slug=slug)
    movie.tracking_id = tracking.tracking_id(request)
    movie.save()
    tracking.log_movie_view(request, movie)
    context = RequestContext(request, {'movie': movie })
    if movie:
        try:
            screener = movie.moviemedia_set.get(movie_type='screener')
            .... continued
```

**UPDATE:**

Here are the contents of filmlibrary/tracking/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from movies.models import Movie

class PageView(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    ip_address = models.IPAddressField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    tracking_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')

class MovieView(PageView):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie)
```

The error appears to come from the import line `from tracking.models import MovieView` in the tracking.py file and I am not sure why. As soon as I comment out that line the error goes away but then of course I'll have new errors about MovieView not existing as expected. I don't see anything wrong with that import line in tracking.py.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why I receive that error and how I can resolve this?

Comment: Is there a `models.py` file in the `tracking` app?

Comment: David, there is... I will update the question with it's contents

Comment: Looks like you need to check your PYTHON_PATH

Comment: @AaronCroyle Django works different than regular Python scripts- they set up the path to have access to all the installed apps.

Comment: Django isn't magic. How are you envoking this when you see the error?

Does the import work from `./manage.py shell`?

Comment: Aaron, of course, otherwise the entire app would break, this import and many other imports are used throughout the project. This is a newly added app that we've added today and I can't figure out why this happens within a single file.

Comment: @JeffC Is there an `__init__.py` file in the `tracking` app?

Comment: Amit, yes, there is, I just triple checked. -rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  0  6 Nov 11:33 tracking/__init__.py I am baffled...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Can you try

**from models import MovieView**

instead of

**from tracking.models import MovieView**

The reason being both models.py and tracking.py are in the same app folder "tracking", you don't need to write tracking.models, this will make Django think that you have a folder named models inside the tracking directory.

Answer (score 14):

Though this is a good solution in some cases, this error can also be caused by app name conflicts with built in apps.

I know that our team has encountered this error and it was because of the actual app name. This is also important to note, because you won't be able to pull in models to other apps if that is the case.

```
#You cannot use this format out of scope
from models import Test

#You can use this both in and out of scope in Django
from myapp.models import Test
```

If the second example isn't working in your Django project you may be using a conflicting app name. Good examples of unusable built in apps include (but are not limited to) "tests", and "admin".

I would caution against a bandaid fix and investigate your app name closely.

Answer (score 1):

Please try -

`from .models import MovieView`

and it should work. The dot before `models` means the current directory.
Both your tracking.py file and models.py file are in the same directory.